# Does a bluetooth device I've already paired with have to be in discoverable mode for me to scan for and see it?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

If I already have paired with a bluetooth device using my mobile app, can I scan to see if I can connect without it having to be in discoverable mode?

I disabled iBeacon broadcasting on my bluetooth modules, and would like my app to know when it is in range (without iBeacon capabilities).

Answer (score 1):

If the device is not in discoverable mode, if you scan, scan result will not show that device. But for the purpose of connection you do not need that. If the device is already paired; its MAC address is already stored and a connection can be established if the device is in range.

As per android documentation.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth

Did I get your question right?

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot!